# Validate :on with custom method in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, validation

I want to do a put/patch to the following route which in return calls the bars controller and calls its update_premium method:
`put '/bar/premium', to: 'bars#update_premium'`

However that method should call a validation check in the model itself whenever .save or .valid?/.valid is called.

`bar.rb`

```
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :city
    validate :validate_premium_bars, on: :create
    validate :validate_premium_bars, on: :update_premium

    def allow
        @allow_change = true
    end

    private
    def validate_premium_bars
        return unless self.city
        unless @allow_change
            if self.city.bars.where(:is_premium => true).count >= 5
                errors.add("...")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

`bars_controller.rb`

```
def update_premium
        @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
        if @bar.save
            ...
        else
            render json: @bar.errors.full_messages, status: 400
        end
end
```

It works when I use `on: :update` however a custom method in the controller such as `on: :update_premium` doesn't work together with the "on:" symbol.

How can I resolve this? I want to keep the update method in the controller for a real full model update and not just for triggering one attribute of the model.

Comment: How are you updating the value in the `update_premium` method? Rails model validation callbacks is supposed to be called on `update` in general and not just the `update` method in the controller.

Comment: @anonn023432 just like so for example: `@bar.is_premium = !@bar.is_premium`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the situation in this question I would actually suggest just adding validation as:

```rb
validate :validate_premium_bars
```

So it runs every time you run `valid?` or `save` is called instead of adding specific conditions for `create` and `update`.

In case, you want to add this separately for some reason. You can add the validation to run for `update` and update the actual attribute using the `update` call or call `valid?` on it after value check to make sure that the record passes validations

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed the most obvious and easiest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `update` controller action is no mapped to the model actions. One refers to an endpoint and the other refers to an event in the model lifecycle.
Looks at the [official documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) about validation options.

You can create a custom conditional validation to run each time the model is changed. For example:

```
  validate :validate_premium_bars, if: :allowed_chage?
 
  def allowed_chage?
    @allowed_chage
  end
```

[soruce](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)